# Source of the Sanskrit shloka- Om Sarva Mangala Mangalye

Tags: identification-request, sanskrit, shloka

The sanskrit shloka given below is a prayer to Goddess Durga.

> Om Sarva Mmangala Mangalye Shive Sarvaartha Saadhike
>
> Sharanye Tryambake Gauri Naaraayani Namostute"

Sarva Mangala Mangalye - To auspiciousness of all auspiciousness

Shiva -to the Good

Sarvarrtha Saadhike - to the accomplisher of all objectives

Sharanye - to the Source of Refuge

Tryambake - to the mother of the three worlds.

Gauri - to the Goddess who is Rays of Light

Naaraayani - Exposer of Consciousness

Namostute- We bow to you.

What is the Source of this prayer to Goddess Durga?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is from **Devi Mahatyam** which is part of Markandeya Purana. When Goddess killed two demons Sumbha and Nisumbha, Devas eulogized Devi with their hymns. This hymn is part of their eulogy to Divine Mother.

*From [Chapter 88](https://www.hinduscriptures.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/24F_Chapter_88_1.pdf)* of *Markandeya Purana* :

> सर्वमङ्गलमाङ्गल्ये शिवे सर्वार्थसाधिके। 
>  शरण्ये त्र्यम्बके गौरि
> नारायणि नमोऽस्तु ते॥९॥
>
> sarvamaṅgalamāṅgalye śive sarvārthasādhike। 
>  śaraṇye tryambake gauri
> nārāyaṇi namo'stu te॥9॥
>
> 9.O you who are beneficent with every happiness, O lady auspicious, who accomplishes every petition, O giver of refüge, O Tryambakä, O
> brilliant one, O Näräyani, reverence to thee!

Comment: @UdayKrishna Which chapter? Same Chapter?

Comment: @UdayKrishna Part 2 https://www.hinduscriptures.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/24F_Chapter_88_2.pdf